# Update/commandbutton doesn't work on primefaces 3.4

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

im trying to display a  form to modify a row in my table when i click an icon but nothing happen when i click , i'm using primefaces 3.4 and i have no problems in my bean , help please

```
       <h:form>


      <h1><h:outputText value="List Des Agents De Ministère"/></h1>


 <p:dataTable value="#{agentBean.agentministeres }"     id="agentList"
              paginator="true" rows="10" var="item">
                               <p:column>
                                    <f:facet name="header">
                                        <h:outputText value="Action"/>
                                    </f:facet>
     <!--the problem in this commmandbutton i don't know if display or oncomplete dosn't word -->         
              <p:commandButton  id="selectButton"  
                                oncomplete="PF('dialog').show()" 
                                update="display" 
                                icon="ui-icon-search" 
                                title="View"/>  

                                </p:column>
                                <p:column>
                                    <f:facet name="header">
                                        <h:outputText value="PrenomAgent"/>
                                    </f:facet>
                                    <h:outputText value="#{item.prenomAgent}"/>
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column>
                                    <f:facet name="header">
                                        <h:outputText value="TelAgent"/>
                                    </f:facet>
                                    <h:outputText value="#{item.telAgent}"/>
                                </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
                           </h:form>
```

and this is the form :

```
       <h:form id="display">
                       <p:dialog header="Details" widgetVar="dialog" resizable="false" id="display"  
            showEffect="fade" hideEffect="explode" modal="true">  

      <h:panelGrid id="display" columns="2" cellpadding="4" style="margin:0 auto;">
                                    <h:outputLabel value="NomAgent:" for="nomAgent" />
                                    <h:inputText id="nomAgent" value="#{agentBean.agentministere.nomAgent}" title="NomAgent" />
                                    <h:outputLabel value="PrenomAgent:" for="prenomAgent" />
                                    <h:inputText id="prenomAgent" value="#{agentBean.agentministere.prenomAgent}" title="PrenomAgent" />
                                    <h:outputLabel value="TelAgent:" for="telAgent" />
                                    <h:inputText id="telAgent" value="#{agentBean.agentministere.telAgent}" title="TelAgent" />
          <p:commandButton value="Valider"  image="ui-icon-disk" action="#{agentBean.enregistrerAgent}"  />
 </h:panelGrid>


</p:dialog>  

          </h:form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following points will help you to fix your code.

1. `update="display"` cannot work since display is not available in the namingcontainer. If the form `<h:form id="display">` should be updated use `update=":display"`
2. Try putting the form inside your dialog, this will solve some problems you will maybe face while if you would update the form via ajax, this would hide the dialog.

   ```
   <p:dialog widgetVar="dialog">
       <h:form id="details">
           <!-- input and commandbutton, now form can easily updated on submit -->
       </form>
   </p:dialog>
   ```
3. You must submit the selected row to the bean to show updates in the detail dialog:

   ```
   <p:commandButton  id="selectButton" icon="ui-icon-search"             
       update="display" 
       oncomplete="dialog.show();">
       <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{agentBean.agentministere} value="#{item}"/>
   </p:commandButton>
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much , the problem is resoved ^^ :D